# Pull specific keys with values to use in bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

My data looks like this

```
var data = [
{'date':'1/1/17', 'cars':2.0, 'trucks':3.0, 'suvs':4.0, 'bikes':0,'skates':0}
{'date':'2/1/17', 'cars':4.0, 'trucks':7.0, 'suvs':4.0, 'bikes':1.0,'skates':0.0}
{'date':'3/1/17', 'cars':0.0, 'trucks':3.0, 'suvs':5.0, 'bikes':0.0,'skates':4.0}
```

I'm trying to plot this in a bar chart using dc or d3, with my x axis being vehicle (bike, truck,skates) and my y axis being the count.

Is there a smart way to do this?

This link is what I'm basing my project
[dc example](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/ordinal-bar.html)
but I think their data formatted differently (i.e.)

```
var data = [
{'name':'apple', 'count':2.0},
{'name':'bannana', 'count':4.0},...]
```

So I don't know if this is even possible

Comment: why would you do something like `d.truck=d.truck`? what's the intention behind it?

Comment: Isn't this how you define it? I want to have d.truck accessible for plotting

Comment: I'm not sure I get it right, but for me it seems, that d.truck has the defined value even before the assignment.

Comment: You are correct.. hmm I believe I need to figure out how to extract the key value to use it for the x-axis. d.truck would be a number

Comment: Please use the dc.js tag for questions about the charting library - dc is quite something else.